# Daily python task crontab

Tags: python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have few independent projects written in Python that I would like to have executed `daily`. I'm going to use crontab on an Ubunutu server but I would like to write a `script` to manage these projects and at the end send a report with information on what scripts failed, what errors they produced, if they were successful, time to execute etc.

I have `2` ideas, please help me decide which one is better or provide me a better solution?

1: `crontab` will execute a bash file and this bash file will launch each script and calculate the time they took to run.

2: `crontab` will execute a python script which will execute all the others scripts and calculate the time they use to run etc.

Sorry english is not my main language.

Comment: Why do some people downvote without any reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Both of these solutions are quite feasible, but it's probably going to be easier to write a script in python (solution #2).

Bash scripts are great, but if you make a bash script here you'd need to write another script that was passed the result of all your other scripts. It would look something like this:

```
##results.sh
first_result = python script1.py
second_result = python script2.py
python email_results.py $first_result $second_result
```

With this methodology it will be difficult to time the scripts and is generally a little unwieldly.

If you used python, you could use time.time() to time things and it would generally be a little neater.

```
##python
import time
import script1

start = time.time()
result = script1()
end = time.time()

time_elapsed = (end - start)

email_results(result, time_elapsed)
```

Hopefully this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I I used python to do it! It's so flexible!
But to call my script I decided to use the "os" command:

```
folderList=next(os.walk('.'))[1]
    for folder in folderList:
        os.chdir(folder)
        res =subprocess.Popen(["venv/bin/python", "main.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    os.chdir("..")
```

It works well and executes all my scripts! Off course I added an exception handler etc. Thank for your answer! :)